# Python print limit to two decimal place

Tags: python

I want to print number in two decimal place, I have the following:

```
a= [ 0.1111113, 0.222222]
print '{0:.2f}, {0:.2f}'.format(a[0], a[1])
```

> output: 0.11, 0.11

But this is not right, it should be 0.11, 0.22, it is not correct!

What is going on?

Comment: '{0:.2f}, {0:.2f}' -> '{0:.2f}, {1:.2f}' (the first number tells you which argument to use)

Comment: After my initial tests, I was thinking you didnt need a key, but putting: `{.2f}` throws an error.  There should be a way to bypass though, im just not sure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are referencing the first (0th) argument to format both times, change to first and second as below:

```
a = [0.1111113, 0.222222]
print '{0:.2f}, {1:.2f}'.format(a[0], a[1])
```

or skip indexing:

```
a = [0.1111113, 0.222222]
print '{:.2f}, {:.2f}'.format(a[0], a[1])
```

or pass all of a to format:

```
a = [0.1111113, 0.222222]
print '{0[0]:.2f}, {0[1]:.2f}'.format(a)
```

[full docs for string formatting with examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Comment: For anyone editing this, the question is clearly about python 2 as the example would not be syntactically valid for python 3. As such this is the correct answer (using print statement). If you want to include python 3 syntax, I'm fine with adding that, but please don't remove the syntax that answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
a= [ 0.1111113, 0.222222]
print '{:.2f}, {:.2f}'.format(*a)
```

If you ever want awesomeness, move to > Python 3.4
Then you can do:

```
a= [ 0.1111113, 0.222222]
print(f'{a[0]:.2f}, {a[1]:.2f}')
```

;)

Comment: how is this different from @simonf solution

Comment: I did not Simons: but sure a= [ 0.1111113, 0.222222]
print '{:.2f}, {:.2f}'.format(*a) is different, no? I removed the part that looks like Simons.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `round()` function:

```
a= [ 0.1111113, 0.222222]
b= [round(i,2) for i in a]
print(b)
# output [0.11, 0.22]
```